# GAM over-parameterization?

Tags: generalized-additive-model

I am fitting a GAM to data of abundance using the `mgcv` package in R. Given that I have a value of abundance for each of 58 different trapping sites from 2005 to 2014, I have 58 observations in my dataset.
The independent variables are mainly proportions of land cover types. 
I logit-transformed the proportion of anthropogenic areas and wetlands for stabilizing the variance. So, the output of the GAM includes the logit-transformation.

```
function(p) { log(p/(1-p)) }
```

To built the GAM, I used proportions of land cover types which were calculated within trapping sites. For details, the land cover types were identified from maps using satellite imagery. I reclassified the land cover types into 10 classes based on ecology of my species. The covariates chosen in the GAMs were firstly tested for collinearity. In the end, I included the proportions of 6 land cover types into the GAMs. x and y are the coordinates of site centroids.

Here is the output of my model:

```
Family: Gamma 
Link function: log 

Formula:
abundance ~ s(x, y, k = 9) + s(p_urban, 
    k = 9, bs = "cs") + s(p_crop, k = 9, bs = "cs") + s(p_forest, 
    k = 9, bs = "cs") + s(p_open, k = 9, bs = "cs") + s(p_wetland, 
    k = 9, bs = "cs") + s(p_grassland, k = 9, bs = "cs")

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  2.55086    0.01236   206.3   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                                   edf Ref.df     F  p-value    
s(x,y)                           5.771  6.499 4.291 0.014444 *  
s(p_urban)                       7.686  8.000 6.621 0.000365 ***
s(p_crop)                        6.542  8.000 5.722 0.000570 ***
s(p_forest)                      7.292  8.000 8.769 1.90e-05 ***
s(p_open)                        7.225  8.000 4.951 0.002075 ** 
s(p_wetland)                     4.170  8.000 3.049 0.002237 ** 
s(p_grassland)                   8.000  8.000 9.843 1.53e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.916   Deviance explained = 98.7%
GCV = 0.049744  Scale est. = 0.0088676  n = 58
```

The residual plots are acceptable.

[image]

I don't have residual autocorrelation.

I would like to use this model for prediction and mapping abundance of my species at large scale. But, I am wondering whether or not this model is open to criticism because the deviance explained and R-squared (adjusted) are very high. Is it possible that I have a over-parameterization problem (in my case, N=58) ? How can I check if my model is over-parameterized ?

**Update**

Here is the output for concurvity

```
> concurvity(mod)
                 para    s(x,y)                       s(p_urban)    s(p_crop)     s(p_forest)   s(p_open)            s(p_wetland)
worst    1.717405e-21 0.9993659                        0.9996937    0.9993160      0.9996920    0.9989277             0.9992618
observed 1.717405e-21 0.9690776                        0.9768057    0.8459540      0.9872601    0.9486973             0.8154789
estimate 1.717405e-21 0.9550265                        0.9040882    0.9055716      0.9111724    0.8792037             0.9062574
                         s(p_grassland)
worst                      0.9987251
observed                   0.8584052
estimate                   0.8713626
```

Comment: First I would refit using `method = "REML", select = TRUE` and remove the `bs = "cs"` bits. (Unless you have a real desire for shrinkage cubic regression splines?) That would help confirm, or otherwise, the results of the GCV smoothness selection which can be problematic. I would also check for concurvity; I find it difficult to imagine the covariates are not dependent on one another in some sense as the total proportion of land cover must equal 1. It's a small sample, but your residuals (top right) have a trend in them.

Comment: Thanks Gavin for your advice. I refitted my model according to your suggestion. Two covariates (s(x,y) and s(p_open) were significant with `R-sq.(adj) =  0.368   Deviance explained = 40.8%`. Is it possible that the use of shrinkage cubic regression splines induces over-parameterization in my case ?

Comment: No, Nell, I think this is an issue of GCV under-smoothing, which is exacerbated because your variables are highly concurved, which is just about the worst conditions for GCV to fail. REML is more robust to this and `select = TRUE` is a more principled form of shrinkage than the shrinkage smoothers. You really need to do something about the concurvity however. Also check output from `gam.check()` to see if any term needs more dfs. Cubic splines have slightly worse MSE performance than thin plate splines, but that isn't the issue here.